# Problem with a bootstrap grid not web responsive

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, grid

I have this Bootstrap grid  https://www.codeply.com/p/FuHGj3t94N
It works fine with large desktop , but on mobile all is messed up.
Especially the "NEW" text is not visible in mobile and is not responsive.
What is wrong in my Bootstrap grid code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Please flow the Bootstrap grid system.

And please see the code here to see your code  [demo](https://www.codeply.com/p/yHYp6GW5M0)

## you should add

```
<div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-2 col-4"
```

and

```
<div class="col-lg-11 col-md-11 col-sm-10 col-8"
```

to make 100% responsive